# Debugging python hug api with pdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pdb, hug

I'm trying to debug a python hug API with `pdb`.

The regular hug api is started with: 
`hug -f api.py`

You can start pdb from the command line via `python` interpreter using:

`python -m pdb api.py`

Where `api.py` contains hug routes, directives etc. `api.py` however needs to be run with `hug -f api.py` which doesn't accept `-m pdb`.

eg: `hug -m pdb -f api.py` doesn't work.

I also tried creating a `debug.py` file and import `api.py` into it with debugging started. But it doesn't register the routes in `api.py`.

```
import pdb
from api import *

@hug.startup()
def startup(args):
    """Starts api and debugging"""
    pdb.set_trace()
```

The hug server starts ok, but without any routes defined in `api.py`.

At the moment I'm resorting to having to put `pdb.set_trace()` directly into one of the routes in `api.py`. This works but is tedious. Ideally there should be a way to start `api.py` with `hug` and `pdb` debugging and set breakpoints dynamically without restarting `hug`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the auto re-loader can not handle with debugger.

Use `--manual_reload` option when start app.

More about this issue [here](https://github.com/timothycrosley/hug/issues/504)